# How to search through array properties in Model

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I have to make a Contacts-like app. I have a model object. Please notice the 2 properties `phoneNumbers` & `addresses` are Arrays

```
class Contact: NSObject {

var name: String?
var companyName: String?
var phoneNumbers: [String]?
var addresses: [String]?

.. // Custom init methods etc

}
```

Now I have to populate these and search them using search View Controller.

I followed the simple way, implemented a searchViewController in TableViewController. Much like here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial

```
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    filteredContacts.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[c] %@ OR companyName CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!, searchController.searchBar.text!, searchController.searchBar.text!)

    let array = (contacts as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    filteredContacts = array as! [Contact]

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

My problem is how to search throught the array of phone numbers and addresses? The above code works good searching through non-array properties, but how to search through the arrays?

Comment: CalZone, the Ray Wenderlich tutorial filter arrays with multiple properties.

Comment: @SteveRosenberg But none of the properties are array. In my model, phoneNumbers & addresses are string arrays

Comment: so you want to search for a specific phone number or address across all contacts and even within the arrays that go with each contact?  You want to return the specific contact that has that address or phone number right?

Comment: @SteveRosenberg Yes, very much how we have in iphones' Contact apps. Each contact can have multiple phone number and addresses

Comment: Okay, then you will have to iterate through the arrays and search each one.  Unfortunately near midnight here and I would quick write a method, but falling asleep.  Tomorrow if you have not figured it out already.

Comment: @SteveRosenberg I'm half asleep myself, I was hoping somebody was up :-) I'll keep question open till morning i guess. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code you paste in a playground to test searching within properties that are arrays.  I kept the search functions simple for clarity, but the code can be shortened using filters and closures.

```
import UIKit

class Contact  {

      var name: String?
      var companyName: String?
      var phoneNumbers: [String]?
      var addresses: [String]?

      init (name: String, companyName: String, phoneNumbers: [String], addresses: [String]) {
            self.name = name
            self.companyName = companyName
            self.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers
            self.addresses = addresses
      }
}

var contacts: [Contact] =
      [(Contact.init(name: "Tom Jones", companyName: "Jones", phoneNumbers: ["111-1111", "111-1112", "111-1113"], addresses: ["Hollywood", "New York"])),
       (Contact.init(name: "Aretha Franklin", companyName: "Franklin", phoneNumbers: ["111-1114", "111-1115", "111-1116"], addresses: ["Detroit", "Hollywood"])),
       (Contact.init(name: "Axel Rose", companyName: "Rose", phoneNumbers: ["111-1117", "111-11128", "111-1111"], addresses: ["London", "New York"])) ]

let phoneNumberSearchString = "111-1111"

func searchByPhoneNumber (searchNumber: String, inDataSet contacts: [Contact]) -> [Contact] {
      var searchResult: [Contact] = []
      for contact in contacts {
            for phoneNumber in contact.phoneNumbers! {
                  if phoneNumber == searchNumber {
                        searchResult.append(contact)
                  }
            }
      }
      return searchResult
}

func searchByAddress (searchAddress: String, inDataSet contacts: [Contact]) -> [Contact] {
      var searchResult: [Contact] = []
      for contact in contacts {
            for address in contact.addresses! {
                  if address == searchAddress {
                        searchResult.append(contact)
                  }
            }
      }
      return searchResult
}

let foundContacts = searchByPhoneNumber("111-1111", inDataSet: contacts)

for contact in foundContacts {
      print(contact.name!)
}

let foundContacts2 = searchByAddress("Hollywood", inDataSet: contacts)

for contact in foundContacts2 {
      print(contact.name!)
}

/* Print results

 Tom Jones
 Axel Rose
 Tom Jones
 Aretha Franklin

 */
```